Tucker's congruence coefficient on entire factor loadings
To my knowledge, Tucker's Congruence Coefficient is used to evaluate the congruence between factors across samples. For example, after performing EFA for a 2-factor model in R, using fa.congruence() yields a matrix like this:
                Sample1_Factor1   Sample1_Factor2
Sample2_Factor1     a              c
Sample2_Factor2     b              d

However, is it also reasonable to calculate congruence between samples themselves, rather than between factors? For instance:
Sample 1:
    Factor_1   Factor_2
Item1   0.8        0.1  
Item2   0.9        0.1
Item3   0.7        0.2
Item4   0.1        0.8
Item5   0.2        0.7
Item6   0.1        0.8

Sample 2:
    Factor_1   Factor_2
Item1   0.6        0.2 
Item2   0.8        0.1
Item3   0.8        0.1
Item4   0.1        0.7
Item5   0.2        0.8
Item6   0.2        0.7

In this situation, can we concatenate the factor loadings from each sample into a single column, as shown below, and then calculate congruence?
Sample 1: (0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8)
Sample 2: (0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7)

Would it be valid to calculate congruence in this way to evaluate factor similarity across samples?
From what I’ve seen in EFA papers, some studies seem to calculate factor similarity between samples this way, but I’m curious about the exact methodology (as those studies did not show the formula or code, e.g.).
Additionally, is it possible to calculate congruence for each item in a similar manner? For example:
For Item 1: Using the two vectors (0.8, 0.1; Sample 1) and (0.6, 0.2; Sample 2), can congruence be calculated?
Could you please let me know if you are aware of any references on this?
